# How do I grey out #if 0'd code in Xcode 6?

Tags: c++, c, xcode, xcode6

```
#if 0
    some code
#else
    some other code
#endif
```

How do I either hide or grey out "some code" [that the preprocessor makes inactive] in Xcode 6?

Comment: No such feature AFAIK. Related menu items are `Preferences.../Text Editing/Code folding ribbon` and `Editor/Code Folding ➤` but neither does exactly what you want.